# XAMPP: MySQL port blocked even when I changed it

Tags: mysql, xampp, port, blocked

Initially I had XAMPP running with MariaDB then realised I need MySQL instead so tried installing MySQL separately (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/) but that got really messy so I uninstalled everything and reinstalled XAMPP with MySQL (https://filehippo.com/download_xampp/).

But MySQL keeps telling me its port is blocked. I couldn't find what was blocking the port so I changed it to **Port: 3308** (originally Port: 3306) in the `my.ini` file and also in the XAMPP Service and Port settings. But I still get an error so now I'm really confused as to why MySQL refuses to work.

Can anyone figure this out?

MySQL Error log:

```
2018-03-17 13:07:28 1a34 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2018-03-17 13:07:28 6708 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Comment: MariaDB is pretty much the same as MySQL..

Answer (score 0):

```
InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
```

It's not a port block, but the problem is with files.

It looks like a disk is full, no rights, or you should use chkdsk. Maybe file ibdata1 is corrupt.

Comment: I looked around and generally if this problem shows, people delete ibdata* files and ib_logfile*'s. I did this and it still didn't fix. But it recreated ibdata1, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1.